# What's an idiom for intentional misinterpretation (of an agreement etc.)?

Tags: idioms, expressions

In Swedish, we have the expression for intentional misinterpretation of the intended content. An example is *we have between two and three million dollars* and someone saying that *two dollars isn't much*. The expression is *he reads the text like Satan reads the Bible*.

What's an English correspondent to that?

Comment: TV Tropes has a ["**Literal-Minded**"](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LiteralMinded) page, which features this example from *Guardians of the Galaxy* - Rocket: *"Drax's people are completely literal. Metaphors are gonna go over his head"*, Drax: *"Nothing goes over my head. My reflexes are too fast. I would catch it."*

Answer (score 2):

***bloody-minded***

informal British

> Deliberately uncooperative.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/bloody-minded)

Given your geography, I would use this idiomatic expression.

It usually refers to people who are...

***deliberately obtuse***

> Annoyingly insensitive or slow to understand.

Ex. 'He wondered if the doctor was being *deliberately obtuse*’

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/obtuse)

Comment: I wonder if it implies being (or deliberately pretending to be) too dumb-witted and unintelligent to understand. The reason for asking is that the Swedish expression kind of bears the connotation of misinterpretation, rather than misunderstanding. The sense conveyed is less of *du'h... I don't get it* but rather *oh, I see, I see, your points is that thing*..Perhaps that distinction isn't achievable in English? Also, it'd be even more neat to see a suggestion that's an expression, rather than a descriptive term, like a proverb or such. Got anything like that?